# Create USER and LOGIN permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, permissions, logins

What permission should I give to a user or role so that it can Create Login or Create User in database.

Comment: See the "Permissions" section of the Microsoft documentation pages:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463(v=sql.100).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed above by Jeremy, permissions can almost always be found on the corresponding reference document within Books Online for SQL Server.  On these reference documents, there is typically a section titled **Permissions** (typically towards the bottom of the document) which contains your desired data.

[CREATE LOGIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (copied directly from the reference)

> Requires **ALTER ANY LOGIN** or **ALTER LOGIN** permission on the server.
>
> *If the CREDENTIAL option is used, also requires **ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL** permission on the server.*

[CREATE USER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (copied directly from the reference)

> Requires **ALTER ANY USER** permission on the database.